# Can a systems developer with NO Java programming experience write Android Apps?

Tags: java, android, programming-languages

I am basically a embedded systems programmer on linux. However, I would like to try my hand at writing Android applications. With no previous Java experience, are there GUI toolkits or something that can help me. Or is it mandatory to learn Java.
Any links, tips for newbies like me will be very helpful

Comment: You will have to learn Java. But if you do embedded (C, or better C++) you should get it pretty quick.

Comment: You might give a try to Google App Inventor here: http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/ no need to write a line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various app builders available for those who do not want to do any programming but they are very limited in the apps they can produce. Basically, such builders offer the developer a series of templates which the developer personalizes before building the app. For instance with a video player template, the developer would choose the look and feel such as background colors etc but the rest of the app would be fixed.

Here is an article that looks at some things to consider before using a No-Programming app- builder

http://hypernextandroid.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/coding-and-no-coding-app-makers/

As you are already a programmer and the Java route is extremely intensive then you could try Basic4Android,  HyperNext Android Creator etc. These have much easier learning curves than the Java/Android SDK approach and can still produce native apps.

Answer (score 2):

I am 2 months late, but I have been using a software called Titanium Studio to develop android apps. You cannot write advanced apps like games, but its good for developing simple apps. If you have a mac, then you can develop for iOS as well.

You will basically use javascript and PHP to write your app, which are much easier than learning JAVA.

Cons-

1. It includes most of the commonly used functions from android, iOS SDK but it is missing a lot as well.
2. The size of the apps will generally in range of 10-20 MB.

Apart from that, If you want to create a simple app and want to do it quick Titanium is the software to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You just require an Android tutorial to get started. Try foolowing links:

- [One](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html)
- [Two](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)
- [Three](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)
- [Four](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html)

Its better if you first try learning some [basics of Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) and then try for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the links. However, I had reached these links with a basic search for Android programming. I was wondering if there were tools that would let me write Apps without any Java coding knowledge

Answer (score 1):

yes.

- [App Inventor for Android](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/) - its simple and easy, no need of any prior Java programming knowledge
- Eclipse with ADT plugin - the better way to develop applications - start with [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)
- For UI development - try inbuilt UI editor with ADT plugin or [DroidDraw](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

Answer (score 0):

Gotta learn Java.  But if you're familiar with C then the syntax will be familiar.  It's object model is pretty simple and it's libraries are great, so it should be fun.  Android, of course, has it's own constraints and best-practices.

Comment: So you are saying the learning curve is not steep ? Would learning Core Java suffice ?

Comment: The learning curve of Java should not be steep.  However, the Android libraries and application lifecycle, etc. are separate and will have their own learning curve.  That said, many of the general constraints of embedded systems programming should be familiar, so the Android learning curve will mainly be in the libraries themselves.